# MySQL query for a many-to-many relationship table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have some problems here and i need help.

I have a table called **posts**, another table called **tags** and many-to-many relationship between them called **item_tags**

Here is the strucutre:

**posts**

- id
- title
- description

**tags**

- id
- name
- seo

**item_tags**

- id
- post_id
- tag_id

So let's say now i want to build a query to match multiple tags by having their tag_id already. For an example let's try to match all posts which has tag_id 11, tag_id 133 and tag_id 182. What i could do was selecting them with OR operator but these are not the results i want because what i want is to match all posts which has all mentioned tags only not just if contains some...

My query was:

SELECT * FROM `item_tags` WHERE tag_id='11' OR tag_id='133' OR tag_id='182'

Which is wrong...

Here is a screenshot of the table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TQVP.png

PS: I want to build a search based on multiple keywords (tags).

Thank you!

Comment: *Which is wrong...* what is wrong with that query?

Comment: The query is not returning results i wanted. It shows posts which has tag_id 11 or tag_id 133 or tag_id 182.. I want it to show me the posts which contains all the tags mentioned...

Comment: group by post_id having count(tag_id) = 3 ?

Comment: Ive tried to create a query but I would guess you have to make at least 2 queries (or exactly 2 queries). You can only select rows and even when joining over all tables you can only select posts which has one of the tags and not all using one query.
`SELECT * FROM tags AS tag 
INNER JOIN item_tags AS itemTag ON itemTag.tag_id=tag.id 
INNER JOIN posts AS post ON itemTag.post_id=post.id
WHERE tag IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY post.id;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all posts that have been tagged with **all** three tags, then you could use:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where exists (select 1 from item_tags a where a.post_id = p.id and a.tag_id = 11)
  and exists (select 1 from item_tags a where a.post_id = p.id and a.tag_id = 133)
  and exists (select 1 from item_tags a where a.post_id = p.id and a.tag_id = 182)
```

If you want posts tagged with **any** of those three tags use:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where exists (select 1 from item_tags a where a.post_id = p.id and a.tag_id = 11)
   or exists (select 1 from item_tags a where a.post_id = p.id and a.tag_id = 133)
   or exists (select 1 from item_tags a where a.post_id = p.id and a.tag_id = 182)
```

Answer (score 0):

Important Note: I have not tested it!

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN(SELECT post_id FROM item_tags WHERE item_tags.tag_id='11' OR item_tags.tag_id='133' OR item_tags.tag_id='182');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group result by post_id and then save only those having all tags linked

```
select * 
from posts 
where id in (
    select post_id 
    from item_tags 
    where tag_id in (11,133,182) 
    group by post_id 
    having count(tag_id)=3
)
```

Comment: This code works, but you have any idea about the code if i want to select from multiple tables? Like item_tags_one, item_tags_two, item_tags_three ? I know i didn't asked this from before but i am curious if i can do it.

For Example: 

item_tags (could be tags for post)
item_languages (could be languages for post)
item_tooltips (could be tootlips for the post)

Comment: Of course, you can union some selects to get list of posts ids

Comment: You can post an example for me please? Thanks

Comment: where id in (
   (select post_id 
    from item_tags 
    where tag_id in (11,133,182) 
    group by post_id 
    having count(tag_id)=3) union (   select post_id 
    from item_tags1 
    where tag_id in (11,133,182) 
    group by post_id 
    having count(tag_id)=3)
)

Comment: I just tested this query: select * 
from posts 
where id in ( 
 (
     select post_id 
     from item_tags 
     where tag_id in (22) 
     group by post_id 
     having count(tag_id)=1
    )
    UNION
    (
     select post_id 
     from item_languages
     where lang_id in (1,3) 
     group by post_id 
     having count(lang_id)=2
    )
) and it gave me an syntax error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION

Comment: i wrote unnecessary braces  select * from posts where id in (  select post_id from item_tags where tag_id in (22) group by post_id having count(tag_id)=1 UNION  select post_id from item_languages where lang_id in (1,3) group by post_id having count(lang_id)=2  )

Comment: Ok, i tried this and it's loading infinitelly then crashes.. https://i.imgur.com/p6kkZy8.png

Comment: Ok,i built it. Seems here it's working without those braces (in my phpmyadmin doesn't) but results are not what i wanted. First of all i made a query to get posts which has tag_id 1 and lang_id 2. It should return post 1 only because that matches what i want but instead it's returning post 1,2,4 and 5 probably because it's checking the tag_id and it is 1 for all those posts. Basically this union it's not filtering results properly.. Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/419a98/3